# Google Cloud Engine: Host error after upgrading instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, bitnami

I can not connect to my website after a cpu upgrade. I just clicked on the apply button below the recommended configuration to upgrade.

Can not access the ssh also.

How to debug this?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you refer to a server resizing when you talked about upgrading your CPU. How did you resize your server, is it running? Did you follow the official documentation? Please take a look to the guides below:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance
https://docs.bitnami.com/google/faq/#how-to-change-the-server-type-or-resize-the-server

Comment: I did the same by clicking the apply button below the recommended upgrade. Now I can not access ssh and I am getting a host error when I try to access my website.